# rsync files with apache permissions over ssh

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-httpd, rsync, php

I'm running a rsync via apache to sync an assets directory

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -l rsync -i /home/rsync/.ssh/rsync -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' /var/www/html/site/Uploads centos@$IP:/var/www/html/site/Uploads
```

This works correctly but the ownership changes from apache to centos as it's the user. I could setup the keys for the apache user however that user can't be logged in so that doesn't work.

How can I get rsync to either run as apache to preserve the ownership or run as the centos user and maintain the owner as apache (cron won't work for my case).

Comment: @roaima missed one at the beginning. It's in PHP but isn't really relevant for the question.

Comment: @roaima fair point that its not a shell script however wouldn't it be the same outcome independent of the language as long as apache is the executing process?

Comment: @roaima Command updated to show it as executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the best way I found is to have a user that has sudo access for only that command and use `--rsync-path='sudo rsync'`. e.g.:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -l rsync -i /home/rsync/.ssh/rsync -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' /path/ --rsync-path='sudo rsync' rsync@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/path/
```

Answer (score 1):

The ownership of files in the target directory is determined entirely by the target account used to create/transfer them. (It's not possible for ordinary accounts to change the ownership of files.)

If you want the target files to be owned by `apache` there are four options that spring to mind

1. Transfer the files, logging in to the target account as the `apache` user. With an `ssh` certificate you can avoid any need to embed a password. You can also set up the `ssh` connection to deny any operation other than running the `rsync` service.
2. Pull the files from the target host. You could set this job up to run under cron on a frequent basis (`rsync` with no work can be a relatively cheap option), or you could get it check for a trigger such as creating a file and only if that is activated run the full `rsync` process.

   In this situation I would have `cron` running on your target host, checking for a file locally every five minutes with a snippet like this

   ```
   test -f "$HOME"/.rsync_trigger && rsync ... && rm -f "$HOME"/.rsync_trigger
   ```
3. Use `inotifywait` to fix up the file ownerships once the files had been copied. This would require the process to run as root, but it could be carefully self-contained so that it could only change the ownerships of files owned by `centos` within the `apache` target directory.
4. Copy the files with `rsync` running as root. Not ideal, but may be necessary if all else fails.

Comment: 1 jumps out as would I'm trying to achieve but as you can't login to as apache (at least on centos) how can I achieve this?

Comment: @Rudiger I assumed when you said _can't login_ this was a policy decision not a technical issue. Of course you will be able to log in as Apache. It may require changing the login shell, setting a password, or possibly even creating the home directory, but it will be perfectly possible. I'll see if I can run up a CentOS VM to see what's required. But looking at those options should be a good start for you. What version of CentOS are you running?

Comment: When trying to run `su apache` it says this account is currently not available. I believe this is a security feature of RHEL. I do believe I can convert the account however I prefer to keep security features.

Comment: @Rudiger RHEL or CentOS? Which version?

Comment: It's CentOS 7. RHEL does the same thing and thats why CentOS inherits it.

Answer (score 0):

Rsync has an option `numeric-ids`, that you may be able to leverage here.

Two things though: make sure, on both your servers, that your apache user has the same numeric ID; and make sure the user running rsync can write/update apache owned files to target.

Comment: so apache would be running rsync on the host, but on the target it's technically centos. I could change it to an rsync user and add it to the apache group but is the security a little bit lower with that?

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't affect it. I think numeric-ids might work if you have the same user-id but different usernames. Sounds pretty edge case.